# Анимация на canvas вырисовывает лишнюю линию на старте

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть canvas, при первом клике на него устанавливается "точка старта", при движении мышки от точки старта до мышки тянется линия, при втором клике линия закрывается и координаты начала/конца пишутся в массив.
Анимация реализована через очистку канваса при движении мышки и повторную отрисовку линии.

Проблема: в момент, когда я начинаю новую линию (кликаю и начинаю двигать мышку), на долю секунды мигает линия, идущая от точки завершения предыдущей линии к мышке, а потом рисуется уже нормальная линия. Если кликнуть неудачно, то именно она пишется в массив. Не могу найти почему это происходит, HELP

```js
    var draw,mouse, array = [],
    mouse = {},
    start_coords= {},
    resault_coords = {},
      preCanvas = document.getElementById("myPreCanvas"), 
                preContext = preCanvas.getContext("2d"),
                pre_w = preCanvas.width,
                pre_h = preCanvas.height;

preCanvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
  if (draw) { 
      draw=false 
      array.push([start_coords.x, start_coords.y, resault_coords.x, resault_coords.y]);
      preContext.clearRect(0, 0, pre_w, pre_h);
  } else {
      mouse.x = e.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
      mouse.y = e.clientY - this.offsetTop;
      start_coords.x=mouse.x ;
      start_coords.y=mouse.y ;   
      draw=true
  }
  });

preCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
  if(draw) {
      mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
      mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

      preContext.clearRect(0, 0, pre_w, pre_h);
      preContext.beginPath();
      preContext.moveTo(start_coords.x, start_coords.y);
      preContext.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
      preContext.stroke();
      preContext.closePath();
  }
});
```

```css
#myPreCanvas {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='myPreCanvas' />
```

Comment: closePath(); - замыкает первую и последнюю точку, зачем тут это?

Comment: Приведите воспроизводимый пример

Answer (score 0):

Чекнул, все работает верно. В предоставленном коде массив, в который добавляются координаты, не используется для отрисовки, так же, в него добавляются неинициализированные свойства объекта resault_coords.